# redhat cluster failover not working (corosync [TOTEM ] Retransmit List)

Tags: cluster, high-availability, rhel6, corosync, cman

I'm using following:

```
[root@kpdbm01 ~]# cat /etc/redhat-release 
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.5 (Santiago)
[root@kpdbm01 ~]# uname -a
Linux kpdbm01 2.6.32-431.20.3.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Jun 6 18:30:54 EDT 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
[root@kpdbm01 ~]# rpm -q rgmanager cman corosync ricci 
rgmanager-3.0.12.1-19.el6.x86_64
cman-3.0.12.1-59.el6_5.2.x86_64
corosync-1.4.1-17.el6_5.1.x86_64
ricci-0.16.2-69.el6_5.1.x86_64
[root@kpdbm01 ~]#
```

I'm trying to use `clusvcadm` to `Disable`/`Enable`/`Relocate` `<group>` yet no matter what I end up with **`Failure`**.

I'm seeing a lot of messages such as one bellow inside of `/var/log/cluster/corosync.log`:

```
Aug 27 19:14:57 corosync [TOTEM ] Retransmit List: 45 46 47 48 49 4a 4b 4c 4d 4e 4f 50 51 52 53 54 55
```

here is output from `/var/log/cluster/rgmanager.log` while I'm trying to `Disable` `PR_MYSQL1`:

```
Aug 27 19:18:31 rgmanager Stopping service service:PR_MYSQL1
Aug 27 19:19:02 rgmanager #52: Failed changing RG status
Aug 27 19:19:02 rgmanager [fs] Checking fs "FS_D", Level 20
Aug 27 19:19:02 rgmanager [fs] Checking fs "FS_L", Level 20
Aug 27 19:19:02 rgmanager [fs] Checking fs "FS_B", Level 20
Aug 27 19:19:02 rgmanager [ip] Checking 192.168.52.34/24, Level 10
Aug 27 19:19:02 rgmanager [ip] 192.168.52.34/24 present on eth0
Aug 27 19:19:02 rgmanager [ip] Link for eth0: Detected
Aug 27 19:19:02 rgmanager [ip] Link detected on eth0
Aug 27 19:19:02 rgmanager [ip] Local ping to 192.168.52.34 succeeded
Aug 27 19:19:02 rgmanager [mysql] Verifying Configuration Of mysql:PR_DB
Aug 27 19:19:02 rgmanager [mysql] Verifying Configuration Of mysql:PR_DB > Succeed
Aug 27 19:19:02 rgmanager [mysql] Monitoring Service mysql:PR_DB
Aug 27 19:19:02 rgmanager [mysql] Monitoring Service mysql:PR_DB > Service Is Running
Aug 27 19:19:05 rgmanager [fs] Checking fs "FS_D", Level 10
Aug 27 19:19:05 rgmanager [fs] Checking fs "FS_L", Level 10
Aug 27 19:19:05 rgmanager [fs] Checking fs "FS_B", Level 10
Aug 27 19:19:05 rgmanager [ip] Checking 192.168.52.34/24, Level 0
Aug 27 19:19:05 rgmanager [ip] 192.168.52.34/24 present on eth0
Aug 27 19:19:05 rgmanager [ip] Link for eth0: Detected
Aug 27 19:19:05 rgmanager [ip] Link detected on eth0
```

and here is output from `clustat`:

```
[root@kpdbm02 ~]# clustat 
Cluster Status for db_prod1 @ Wed Aug 27 19:16:15 2014
Member Status: Quorate

 Member Name                                                     ID   Status
 ------ ----                                                     ---- ------
 kpdbm01-224                                                         1 Online, rgmanager
 kpdbm02-224                                                         2 Online, Local, rgmanager

 Service Name                                                     Owner (Last)                                                     State         
 ------- ----                                                     ----- ------                                                     -----         
 service:PR_MYSQL1                                                kpdbm02-224                                                      started       
[root@kpdbm02 ~]#
```

any ideas what's wrong? and how I can tackle it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As work around the communication difficulties, changing cluster communication from the default Multicast to Unicast:

```
<   <cman expected_votes="1" two_node="1"/>
---
>   <cman expected_votes="1" two_node="1" transport="udpu"/>
```